# Usar dados de uma $_SESSION em Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, session

Fala galera, todos bem?

Estou apanhando com algo que acredito que deveria ser algo simples. Tenho essa funçãozinha em javascript onde de acordo com o nível do usuário deveria fazer envio para páginas diferentes.

Exemplo, se o usuário da Sessão for nível 1 deve fazer o POST para busca_relatório2.php, se o usuário for nível 3 enviar para busca_relatorio3.php.

Com a função que fiz ele acaba enviando pros dois e a página fica brigando usando um e outro.

O que tentei fazer foi isso:

```
var nivel = <?php echo $_SESSION['nivel']; ?>;

    if(nivel = 1){
        $('#btn_buscar').click( function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'inc/busca_relatorio2.php',
                method: 'post',
                data: $('#resultado_busca').serialize(),
                sucess: function(data){
                    $('#resultado_busca').val('');
                }
            });
        });
        $('#form_data').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'inc/busca_relatorio2.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: { busca_data: $('#busca_data').val()}, // sua data chegará como $_POST['busca_data'] no PHP.
            success: function(data){                                                        
                 return false; //não vai redirecionar a lugar algum
            }
        });                 
    });             
    }

    if(nivel = 3){
        $('#btn_buscar').click( function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'inc/busca_relatorio3.php',
                method: 'post',
                data: $('#resultado_busca').serialize(),
                sucess: function(data){
                    $('#resultado_busca').val('');
                }
            });
        }); 
        $('#form_data').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'inc/busca_relatorio3.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: { busca_data: $('#busca_data').val()}, 
            success: function(data){ 
                 return false; //não vai redirecionar a lugar algum
            }
        });                 
    }
```

Se eu debugar a minha `$_SESSION` mostra certinho o usuário logado e o nível dele.
 Essa parte do meu código está em um arquivo `header.php` que contém toda a estrutura inicial das minhas páginas. Imaginei que como já tenho o `session_start()` setado no começo da página poderia usar esse comando. Será que estou misturando demais (pelo fato de php ser server-side e javascript client-side)?

Valeu meus caros. Tenham todos um bom dia =)

Answer (score 1):

O fato de ambos os laços if estarem executando é um equivoco entre o operador de atribuição (`=`) e o operador de comparação (`==`). Então basta corrigir para:

```
...
...
if(nivel == 1){
...
...
...
if(nivel == 3){
...
...
```

> Será que estou misturando demais (pelo fato de php ser server-side e javascript client-side)?

Sim. Essa validação poderia ser feita apenas com PHP. Você poderia criar um novo arquivo `.php` (`busca_relatorio.php`, por exemplo). Ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
$nivel = $_SESSION['nivel'];
if($nivel == 1){
    //chame alguma função, inclua algum arquivo
}else if($nivel == 3){
    //chame alguma função, inclua algum arquivo
}
```

E depois, ,nas requisições ajax, basta chamar o arquivo `busca_relatorio.php`, que ele decidirá o que deverá ser retornado.

Comment: Acabei percebendo que meu problema está em uma outra função onde faço o retorno das funções, então mesmo colocando esse filtro ainda terei erros. 
Mas obrigado ainda assim, vou organizar melhor meu código :)